# How to add the Teradata QUALIFY keyword to the end of a SQLAlchemy core statement?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'm trying to rewrite some raw Teradata SQL to SQLAlchemy Core and have run into a snag with the `QUALIFY` keyword. For example, given the code below:

```
SELECT itemid, sumprice, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sumprice DESC)
FROM (SELECT a1.itemid, SUM(a1.sale) AS sumprice
      FROM sales AS a1
      GROUP BY a1.itemid) as t1
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sumprice DESC) <= 100;
```

I can rewrite most of it as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func

engine = create_engine('teradatasql://user:password@server/logmech=LDAP&encrpytdata=true')
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

a1 = Table('sales', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine).alias('a1')

t1 = select([a1.c.itemid, func.sum(a1.c.sale).label('sumprice')]).group_by(a1.c.itemid).subquery()

sql = select([t1.c.itemid, t1.c.sumprice, func.rank().over(order_by=t1.c.sumprice.desc())])
sql = sql.select_from(t1)
```

If I were to print this code to `stdout` like this for example:

```
print(sql.compile(engine, compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
```

it would give me the exact query as above except for the last line. How do I get that `QUALIFY` line in there?

Comment: I don't think sqlalchemy will emit the (Teradata-specific) `QUALIFY` syntax. But you could make your existing SQL a subquery (say t2) and then apply a WHERE clause in the outer query.

Comment: Hi @Fred. thank you so much for your thoughts. I've tried that. Teradata does NOT like the `QUALIFY` clause inside the `WHERE`. It really needs to hang around as it's own thing at the end. So far, the only way I've stumbled on an answer is to convert the `sql` above to a string and use a SQLAlchemy `text` function to create the `QUALITY` piece.  I then have to join the two strings. It's very bothersome because lots of people internally use `QUALIFY` which makes my job much harder than it needs to be. If I could just add a line to the end of the statement somehow then I've got it.

Comment: Don't use QUALIFY at all. For this case, generate `SELECT itemid, sumprice, theRank FROM (SELECT itemid, sumprice, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sumprice DESC) as theRank FROM (SELECT a1.itemid, SUM(a1.sale) AS sumprice FROM sales AS a1 GROUP BY a1.itemid) as t1) as t2 WHERE theRank <= 100;`